# Windows 11 File Explorer - Intermittent Slowness

Tags: windows, performance, windows-explorer, windows-11

I'm beginning to get very frustrated with Windows Explorer.

Specs:
Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎2021-‎07-‎29
OS build    22000.348
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.348.0

(I'm on the Beta channel)

Windows Explorer is very slow (5-10 second opening time, blue loading cursor) when:

- Navigating files normally in the "main" pane (double-clicking folders, opening files)
- Right-clicking on anything, anywhere

However, it's regular speed when:

- I'm using the standard file picker (i.e. Open/Save)
- I utilize the breadcrumb bar to drill down into file trees (vs double clicking folders in the main pane):
  Screenshot of breadcrumb nav
- I click on any folder/drive in the quick access sidebar

I've had these issues since upgrading to Windows 11 in the summer.

Any ideas what may be causing this? Any temporary fixes?

Would be glad of your help.

Comment: Your question is missing the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can try:

**1. First, DISM / SFC:**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**2. Windows 11 Repair Install:**

If this does not work (and DISM / SFC are basic and have limitations) you may need to try a Windows 11 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. Use the Download button to create a USB
> Windows Installation key, then run Setup on the USB Key.
>
> Running Setup will launch the Repair Process.

I have done this on Windows Insider (Beta) and it works fine.